# GitHub markdown bullets not displaying in Chrome

Tags: list, google-chrome, github, markdown, bulletedlist

I created a README.md github markdown file for the syllabus for the class for which I am using a github repo (https://github.com/rickecon/OGcourse_F16) as our central file and communications interaction hub. The bullets in the list structures throughout the README.md are not displaying in the Chrome browser, but they are displaying in Safari. Any ideas how to fix this, or is it an incompatibility between Chrome and GitHub markdown? My operating system is Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Bullets are working fine for me in Chrome. Are you sure you don't have some local non-standard modifications to your browser, perhaps local style sheets?

Comment: How would I check for local non-standard modifications to my browser? I just downloaded Chrome two months ago, and it says it is up-to-date in Chrome Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bullets are working fine for me on all my computers, all using Chrome. I suspect the problem might be caused by some extension you have installed in Chrome, messing with the style of the website or similiar. You can test this by either disabling all your extensions by going to `chrome://extensions/` and unchecking ´Enable´ for all your extensions, or by going into ingocnito (press `Ctrl + Shift + N`) and go to your repo from there. The Incognito approach will of course only work if you haven't also enabled the extension in Incognito, but it's generally a quick and easy way to test a website without your extensions.

If the bullets now work, try to turn your extensions on one by one to determine which of them cause the problem.

Comment: Yes. It was some extension. It was not any of my Google extensions, but it was either a Pinterest extension (which my wife loaded on my machine clandestinely) or an extension called GitPrint. My money is on GitPrint, although the universe was probably punishing me for having a Pinterest extension.